# Airflow DAG task not running as it is stuck in the 'None' state

Tags: python, airflow

I am building my first ever Airflow DAG. For some reason, my airflow task is not working.

This is the error I get when on task instance details:

[image]

As well, here is main graph overview:

[image]

Here is the main code of the DAG:

```
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2020, 3, 2),
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'schedule_interval': '@once',
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(seconds=5),
}

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='twitterScraper', 
    description='twitter scraper',
    default_args=default_args)


extract = PythonOperator(
    task_id='extract_data', 
    python_callable=extractFunc, 
    dag=dag)

transform = PythonOperator(
    task_id='transform_data', 
    python_callable=transformFunc, 
    dag=dag)

load = PythonOperator(
    task_id='load_data', 
    python_callable=loadFunc, 
    dag=dag)


extract >> transform >> load
```

Comment: Can you include the python source for the dag?

Comment: Just for this specific task or the whole dag?

Comment: Ideally the minimal dag which reproduces the issue- try removing tasks from the dag first and see if you can figure out which parts are necessary to get the same error.

Comment: Ok will do, however I think that its definitely this task thats the problem

Comment: Yep, if you can reproduce the issue with a dag containing only that task that works- just something that people can run themselves & get the same error.

Comment: I still have the same error with just one task running

Comment: Add the source code to your question, or some similar code which generates the same error if you don't want to share the exact code